# Laravel 7 Redirect Login Authorization

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I'm currently using template for my view using jQuery, HTML, and CSS.

When I tried to use middleware to authenticate the user role before accessing routes ,I stumble upon this error.

Error:
[image: Error]

> View [authorization.login] not found.

Is it because I use a different name or custom login for my page? How can I change the link to my current login address?

Here are my routes

```
Route::get('/user-register-page', 'LoginUserController@registerUserPage')->middleware(['auth','auth.admin']);

Route::post('/register-user', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('register');
```

And here's my controller

```
class LoginUserController extends Controller
{

    public function registerUserPage(){
        return view('user-register');
    }

    public function loginUserPage(){
        return view('user-login');
    }

    // public function registerNewUser(Request $request){
    //     dd('test');
    // }

    // public function loginUser(){


    // }


}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of `LoginUserController@registerUserPage` ? that will help me help you. Also, please let me know the names of your views, they're under `resources/views`

Comment: hi @DanielLogvin sure sir!

Comment: Can you please also show the name of your folders in views and the name of the files please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `resources` folder inside `views` you will find a folder called `auth`, in case it is not there, create a folder called `auth` and drag in your file `user-login` and rename it to `login`.